# C++ input in text based games

Tags: c++, cout, cin

I'm making a text based adventure games.

In the intro I make the game asks for the players' name, and they must input their name, and then it'll display their names back on an output.

```
cout << "U.S Soldier: Who's your name, Soldier?" << endl;
_getch();
cout << "Type Your name: ";
cin.getline(name, 50);
cout << "U.S Soldier: I'm DIAZ, now let's go, " << name << "!!" << endl;
```

Then it'll go to another segment(I use the void command).

```
void prologue()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "----------------------- PROLOGUE -------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Diaz: come on, " << name << ", there's no time for rest!!" << endl;
}
```

but on that segment the program seems to forgot the input (player names) from  last segment.

It only displayed as "1" rather than the "name" we input before

How can I make the program keep the player names for entire gameplay?

This is all the code:

```
// getting player's name

void name()
{
    system("cls");
    char name[50];
    cout << "U.S Soldier: Hey, Wake Up!!" << endl;
    _getch();
    cout << "You: (regain conciousness)" << endl;
    _getch();
    cout << "U.S Soldier: Who's your name, Soldier?" << endl;
    _getch();
    cout << "Type Your name: ";
    cin.getline(name, 50);
    system("cls");
    cout << "U.S Soldier: Hey, Wake Up!!" << endl;
    cout << "You: (regain conciousness)" << endl;
    cout << "U.S Soldier: Who's your name, Soldier?" << endl;
    cout << "U.S Soldier: I'm DIAZ, now let's go, " << name << "!!" << endl;
    _getch();
    prologue();
}

// Intro (Prologue)

void prologue()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "----------------------- PROLOGUE -------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Diaz: come on, " << name << ", there's no time for rest!!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `name` is a local variable, it is only known in the `name()` function. You should declare that array in the global scope.

Comment: This is C++, please *do not* use char arrays as strings. Use `std::string` or another string class.

Comment: Your code seems to be repeating `cout` and `_getch()` sequence a lot of times. You should make a function for it, it helps the code to be maintainable. Whenever you wanted a change (add formatting, for example), you could do it in one place then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` you populate is local to the `name()` method.

In `prologue()`, `name` is the method `name()`, not the string you were expecting.

You could make `name` (the string) global. I'd also avoid having variables and methods with the same name (at least until you're a bit more proficient with th language).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in your question itself.

***How can I make the program keep the player names for entire gameplay?***

If you know about the scope and lifetime of variables, you would know that the name you populated is declared in name(), and hence it is local to that function, it can't be accessed outside of that function. To make it accessible throughout the program, declare it as global variable.

Also the name which you are using in prologue(), is the function name(), not the variable you have populated.

Comment: oops,sorry, I don't know I using the same name for variable and the function, thanks by the way..

Answer (score 0):

you can consider doing this cin.getline(name, 50); in the main or rather create a character object and assign this name to the character object

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable inside a block/function, it is local to that block/function. Here you can use name variable inside name() function. To use it in another function either declare it globally(i.e. outside all functions) or pass it as an argument to prologue() function. Also avoid using same/similar name for different identifiers.